# Can I publish Drive App directly from Google Apps Script Editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, publish, google-apps

I want to publish App directly from Google Script Editor to Web Store with marking "Work with Google Drive", so that the App can appear inside Google Drive's Store. But I cannot find "Container" option to set "GOOGLE_DRIVE" in the setting interface.

I have never received reply in this forum. Hope this question can be answered by some kind people.

N.B. I can achieve the task by by manually upload manifest.json with GOOGLE_DRIVE container set inside. But I don't prefer this approach, since it will break my direct linkage with Google Script Editor and affect the convenience. I am also using Google Apps account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not possible. You can publish add-ons directly but not a a Drive app.